# PHP string array UTF-8 encoding fails

Tags: php, apache2

Everything is set to UTF-8 (file encoding, MySQL [however I don't use it], Apache, meta, mbstring etc...) but check this out:

```
$s="áéőúöüóűí";
echo $s; //works perfectly

echo $s[0] // doesn't work. Prints out a single '?'.
```

I have tried almost everything. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely correct behavior.

if you want to get a first *letter* from a *multi-byte string*, not first byte from *binary string*, you have to use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb_substr):

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo mb_substr($s,0,1);
```

Comment: Is there an other way? What causes this anyway? Maybe a new PHP version, because this was not a problem lately?

Comment: Other way for *what*? and *why*? What certain problem you have at the moment?

Comment: I have already written a CMS system and it could not handle this issue... It would be a huge problem if I should to rewrite all the code.

Comment: Do you really have this silly syntax sugar more than once or twice in all the code? I just can't believe it. For what, on the Erath, purpose you are using it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [mb_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions for multibyte strings. [mb_substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) in your case.

Answer (score 0):

And if you define $s[0]="á", does it work ? I believe that when encoded in UTF-8, those special chars are stored over two UTF-chars.

If you display in ANSI some UTF-8 text, it is rendered like this :
Ã¡Ã©oÃºÃ¶Ã¼Ã³uÃ­

You see that á becomes Ã¡
So rendering the first char ($s[0]) would only display the "Ã­", which is an incomplete character

Comment: When I define $s[0]="á"; and echo $s[0]; it works perfectly, but no matter what I do, I don't get any Ã¡ or strange characters.

Answer (score -1):

you have to make some changes in database go to the the table structure

you can find a column "Collation"

which column you want to change click edit on right side menu

the default Collation is - 'latin1_general_ci'  change it to 'utf8_general_ci'[image]